Process for Accessing QEMU Guest on Linux Host
What is the best way to port forward to a QEMU Guest so that one may access it remotely via specific port?
I was looking to set this permentently and i cannot find a reasonable source on google that applies to all KVM variants for setting a qemu:arg with hostfwd in the XML file.
This doesn't write it for each boot https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking

what do you mean by applies to all KVM variants? in what way are there variants of KVM?

Are you actually using libvirt instead of qemu directly? Since you mentioned XML.

@JaromandaX i guess i should say what ever the difference between vmware, proxmox and qemu is. I believe they are all using kvm or based on kvm?

@John Ok but once i do that how do i allow the remote user to reach the virtual guest? Last time i tried that iirc i still couldn't reach the guest even after verifying config with firewall-cmd and iptables. I'm happy to try again though.

@TomYan I'm kind of going between both? Like i try to do as much in virt-manager as i can but i end up finding the file and using something not vim or micro to edit the xml. Thats the only way i know how to make network changes persistent with kvm.

kvm isn't relevant to device emulation / networking part. When you use proxmox or libvirt, often the VMs would leverage the networking stack of the kernel side (e.g. bridges; "NAT" one or not) instead of qemu "slirp". vmware and virtualbox does not use qemu at all and has subtle differences in terms of networking too. (libvirt isn't really equivalent to virt-manager; but virt-manager pretty much implies libvirt).

I am not really sure if libvirt has simple (as in, docker-like) way for you expose a port of a VM. The reason is that it uses an "external" daemon for DHCP (dnsmasq). So you probably have to make the VM use static IP instead, and you may have to configure iptables on the VM host yourself. An easier way would be to just make the VM use "bridged" networking (aka an "external" bridge instead of the default "NAT bridge"), which eliminates the need of "double" port forwarding if you need some service/port of the VM accessible from the Internet. (But I hardly know libvirt, so.)

If you only need to access it from the VM host (but not its physical "neighbors" or the Internet), IIRC it works out of the box with the NAT bridge. (But again, look out for firewall configuration.)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
